# Why are my map values incorrect?

Tags: java, dictionary

```
    String a = "Some small sample text!";
    char[] letters = a.toCharArray();
    int[] charvals = new int[letters.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<letters.length;i++) {
        int curr = (int) letters[i];
        charvals[i] = curr;
       }
    HashMap<Character, Integer> lettermap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    Character c;
    for (int i = 0; i<letters.length; i++) {
        c = letters[i];
        if (lettermap.containsKey(c)) {
            lettermap.put(c, lettermap.get(c) + 1); }
        else {
            lettermap.put(c, 1); }}
    for (int i = 0; i < charvals.length; i++) {
        if (charvals[i] !=32) {
        c = letters[i];
        System.out.println(lettermap.get(c));
    }
```

`1 1 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 3 1 2 1`

This is the output, horizontally for space concerns. I should only have 3 "3s" or letters that appear 3 or more times, but I get 9. Can anybody tell me why?

It is easy to see on the 3rd item of output. The key is 'm' in my String and it is the first time it is appearing in the map yet the value is 3 and not 1. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your program is trying to achieve? How *should* the output look?

Comment: This is just a piece of a much bigger program and I took this chunk out because it is the only part not behaving correctly. The output should look like below.

Comment: 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 1 3 2 1 3 1 2 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < charvals.length; i++) {
    if (charvals[i] !=32) {
    c = letters[i];
    System.out.println(lettermap.get(c));
}
```

This goes through every character in the original string -- *not* uniqued -- and prints outs its count in the map.  So if there are three 'c's in the string, it'll print out the count (3) for 'c' three times.

You probably want to iterate over `lettermap.entrySet()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is ok really, the only problem is in the output. You are taking individual characters of your input string and outputting their counts, like this:

```
S o m e s m a l l s a m p l e t e x t  
1 1 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 3 1 2
```

Try using `lettermap.keySet()` instead:

```
for (Character c2 : lettermap.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", c2, lettermap.get(c2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I see it now. Instead of the count I just need to know that it did in fact appear that many times. I can iterate over entrySet or just add all the elements with a 3 or higher to a Set and get the length of that, since it will remove dups and memory is not an issue right now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your program currently only outputs the *final* counts for the characters present in your String.

To print a running total, you would print the value present in the `Map` after the value is changed by adding a print statement to your second for loop, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    c = letters[i];
    if (lettermap.containsKey(c)) {
        lettermap.put(c, lettermap.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        lettermap.put(c, 1);
    }
    System.out.print(lettermap.get(c) + " ");
}
```

This prints the following output: `1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 3 1 3 1 2 1`

If you then add some logic to print the character that is being counted, the following is returned:

`{'S'=1, 'o'=1, 'm'=1, 'e'=1, ' '=1, 's'=1, 'm'=2, 'a'=1, 'l'=1, 'l'=2, ' '=2, 's'=2, 'a'=2, 'm'=3, 'p'=1, 'l'=3, 'e'=2, ' '=3, 't'=1, 'e'=3, 'x'=1, 't'=2, '!'=1}`

Answer (score 0):

Just going to leave this here for anyone interested:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CharacterCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print("Some small sample text!");
    }

    public static void print(String str) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
            map.put(c, 1 + (map.containsKey(c) ? 1 : 0));
        }

        List<Character> cList = new ArrayList<Character>(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(cList);

        for (Character c : cList) {
            System.out.printf("'%c' - %d%n", c, map.get(c));
        }
    }
}
```

***Prints:***

```
' ' - 2
'!' - 1
'S' - 1
'a' - 2
'e' - 2
'l' - 2
'm' - 2
'o' - 1
'p' - 1
's' - 2
't' - 2
'x' - 1
```